# Плохо ли сбрасывать каждый раз кэш у JS или CSS файлов?

Tags: javascript, кэширование

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/all.js"></script>
```

В такое случае, если я отредактирую файл, то придётся сбросить кэш(CTRL+R), чтобы увидеть изменения. Чтобы этого не делать, я делаю так:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/all.js?<? echo rand(); ?>"></script>
```

то есть каждый раз сбрасываю кэш.

Нормально ли это?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В процессе разработки - вполне нормально. А в продакшене такие трюки ни к чему: накопили пакет изменений - поменяли цифру после */js/all.js?* и */css/style.css?* Но не в коем случае не делайте там рандом - лишние обращения к серверу ни к чему, вы же не вносите изменения **между каждым** обращением пользователя к сайту?

Если изменения так и прут, возможно, имеет смысл повременить с выходом в продакшен или разделить версию для разработки и версию для всех.

Answer (score 2):

Плохо, особенно для мобильных клиентов, сбрасывайте кеш только если файл был изменен, например так:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/all.js?<?= filemtime($JS_PATH . "all.js") ?>"></script>
```

Либо заведите переменную **$JS_BUILD** (чтобы не использовать filemtime) и изменяйте её во время раскладки на боевой сервер, главное чтобы эта переменная обновлялась автоматически и только в случае изменения нужных файлов.